# How would I override the tickIcon for multiple selections in bootstrap-select and change to highlighting the selections instead?

Tags: bootstrap-select

The example given in bootstrap-select works by adding a tickicon to every selection. How would I override this feature so I can highlight my selections instead of adding a tickicon? I tried setting data-show-tick to false, but that doesn't seem to work for multiple selections.

I'm not sure where to go. Would appreciate advice.

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by hidding the tick icons with CSS.

For this, you may use the following css rule in your own css file (declared after the original bootstrap-select.css file) :

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark { display: none !important; }
```

Or you can alter the original rule of the bootstrap-select.css file by changing it for :

```
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark { position: absolute; display: none; right: 15px; margin-top: 5px; }
```